# Why does the forEach() method exist for object keys but not array keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I do this in node (v10.15.3):

```
Object.keys({test: 'test'}).forEach(() => console.log('gfg'));
```

I get:

```
gfg
```

If I do:

```
Array(3).keys()
```

I get:

```
Object [Array Iterator] {}
```

So I clearly have a type that is in some sense iterable.

However,

```
Array(3).keys().forEach(() => console.log('gfg'));
```

'Yields':

```
TypeError: Array(...).keys(...).forEach is not a function
```

Why does the forEach function not exist on this iterable object when the keys are derived from an array?

Comment: Note the difference in how you're calling them; `Object.keys(obj)` is calling a static method of `Object`, passing in the object as a parameter. `Array(3).keys()` is creating an array, then calling a `keys()` method on the instance.

Comment: @charlietfl my array values are all undefined. I was under the impression from the documentation I was reading that .keys() doesn't ignore undefined values, which is why I was using it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476 check this answer it has all the details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `Array.keys` is **NOT** the same as [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

[`Array.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) return an **iterator** (or, really an "Array Iterator"), it doesn't expose any array prototype because it does **not** return an array, though it can be looped:

```js
for (var elem of Array(3).keys()){
 console.log(elem);
}

// If you really want to use forEach...
[...Array(3).keys()].forEach(k => console.log('spread syntax -> ', k));

// Or using Array.from
Array.from(Array(3).keys()).forEach(k => console.log('Array.from ->', k));
```

#### So, what is the difference?

The difference is that `Array.keys` returns an **iterable**, while `Object.keys` returns an **array**. Because `Array.keys` returns an iterable, it **can't** directly use array methods, because it's just an iterable (or, really, something that has a [[Symbol.iterator]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator). `Object.keys`, instead, returns an **array**, hence it can use any of its prototypes and, since it's an array, also happens to be iterable because, as mentioned before, `Array` is a built in type that [has a default iteration behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator#Description).

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to have the forEach method on the iterator, or is that not how things work?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter `forEach` is a **method**, an iterator is just a different type. Foreach is an Array's prototype method, an iterator is **not** an array. You can conveniently use the spread operator or Array.from if you want to use `forEach` though, since you can build an array out of an iterator (see the updated code above)

Comment: So we can call the spread operator on the iterator...?? could you explain why this helps us?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter the spread operator just collects all the values from an `iterator` or, really, anything that has a `[Symbol.iterator]` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator). You are confusing iterators an arrays: they are **different types**. You can think an iterator as some sort of **interface** that allows something to be able to be **looped**. The spread syntax (...) is a shorthand for collecting all the values of an iterable, hence you can use the spread syntax to build an array out of an interator.

Comment: If you want to, I can try to give you a further explanation, it's just that **arrays are iterables**, but an **iterator is not an array**. Both can be looped in a for loop, but **forEach** is an **array method**. `Array.keys` returns an **iterator**, it does NOT return an array, while `Object.keys` returns an **array**. Both can be looped (because they conveniently are iterable, however `Array.keys` is not an array, hence it cannot use `.forEach` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it back to an array and then iterate over it

```js
([...Array(3).keys()]).forEach(() => console.log('gfg'));
```

you can see the keys() doesnt return an array

```js
console.log(Array.isArray(Array(3)));
console.log(Array.isArray(Array(3).keys()));
```

Comment: Ah, so the array prototype has the forEach method but an iterator doesn't. This seems odd to me...

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter foreach is an array prototype method and will on arrays only not objects https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach